# Sephardic Music Books

Tags: product-recommendation, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, music

The Judaica stores by my house have lots of Ashkenazi music books written in sheet music, but nothing for Sephardic music. Does anyone know of any websites or titles of music books for Mizrahi style Sephardic music? I'm more interested in the music of the prayers, but any music books will do for the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure music that's not prayer (or otherwise Judaism-oriented) oriented would be on topic. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1792/759

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Offtonic NusachDB](http://offtonic.com/nusach).  I'm not sure what you're looking for specifically, but I've added lots of Sephardic/Mizrahi transcriptions there.

Comment: Where on your websites are transcriptions? Btw, i've used and referred many to your site. It's amazing.

Comment: @Aaron Well, here's a Syrian medley for Yom Zeh L'yisrael: http://offtonic.com/nusach/index.html?nid=13&sidpath=,3126,3127,3131&tid=1891&o=1  Other stuff is around!

Answer (score 1):

Also, if u want to know how sephardim make our prayers, we do it after maqam, the Arabic musical system which is hard to master. The website https://pizmonim.org/ also  has the ways to use the maqamim in davening.

Comment: Hello, Mi Yodeya isn't like a regular forum. If you want to add to your answer, a second post is usually unnecessary. Simply edit the additional information into your first answer. I recommend taking the site [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how things work here.

Comment: There are a lot of books of baqashot, but not with the music written out which is what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Im quite amazed by this question. Mizrachim and sephardim have much more songs and book and websites than the ashkenazim. Try https://pizmonim.org/
if u want books, try shir ushbacha

Comment: Does this answer the question? I don't see sheet music on that site.

Comment: @Harel13 sephardic music is usally played on a oud, not a guitar or a piano. so yeah.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/49005)

Comment: Don't oud players need some form of musical notes as well? I doubt they just play what comes to mind.

Comment: @Harel13 im quite sorry but u probbaly wont find notes for sephardic songs. They are not that easy to find and i doubt there is any